# Mavericks+: (Desktop Wallpaper) How can I use both the Apple Desktop Pictures and a local folder?

Tags: macos, system-settings

I enjoy the built in wallpapers that are shipped with Mavericks, but I also want to supplant those with the wallpapers that I have within my user folder.

In System Preferences -> Desktop & Screen Saver, the option only appears to be EITHER the Apple -> Desktop Pictures OR Folders -> My local wallpaper folder.

Does anyone know of a way to blend the two and have both sets cycle through?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can move your wallpapers into `/Library/Desktop Pictures/` and have them in single location. This shouldn’t affect the system because I have the wallpapers since Leopard and each OS update only include more wallpapers.

Go ahead and include yours in there. Make sure you make a backup of `/Library/Desktop Pictures/` just in case you want to revert them back to default state.

Comment: Or move the ones in /Library to your User Library, where you won’t run in to permissions snags.